# SonicWall NAT64

Tags: nat, ipv6, sonicwall

I need to forward IPv6 packets to internal IPv4 server. Please see below my description and attempts made. I'm working with `SonicWall` appliance.

WAN interface has both IPv4 and IPv6 active. DNS is set:

`www.example.com` points to IPv4.
`mailer.example.com` points to IPv6.

DNS has already propagated.

I need IPv4 packets to go to `nginx` server (IPv4), and IPv6 packets to go to `mailer` server (also IPv4). Both `nginx` and `mailer` servers are on the same interface, X2.

For testing purposes, I created an `nginx` rule to listen to `mailer.example.com` and return an internal test HTML file, but it returns:  "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" to the browser.

I understood that I need to create a `NAT64` policy to make this translation.

At `SonicWall` when I go to "add" a NAT policy and select `NAT64 only` I must provide:

- IPv6 original source
- Translated IPv4 source
- Pref64
- Inbound interface
- Outbound interface

I provided "IPv6 original source: public IPv6", "Translated IPv4 source: nginx IPv4" and don't know what to provide for "Pref64".

Interfaces are left with "Any". All NAT policies I've created for this purpose remains with "usage count = 0".

I have tried "Pref64" with: Well-Known Pref64; U0 IPv6 Primary Static Address Subnet; IPv6 Link-Local Subnet; X1 IPv6 Primary Static Address Subnet.

I've already marked "enable IPv6 = yes" at `SonicWall` settings.